# $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}>2$, same answer but different solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I can find the answer (correct?) to the following
$$
\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}>2 \tag 1
$$
However according to the book my solution is "wrong". Why is that? Which lines are wrong?
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2&>2ab\tag 2\\
a^2-ab&>ab-b^2\tag 3\\
a(a-b)&>b(a-b)\tag 4\\
a&>b \tag 5
\end{align}

I also tried the following and found the same answer:
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2-2ab&>0\tag 6\\
(a-b)^2&>0\tag 7\\
a>b \tag 8
\end{align}

What is the difference between the solutions?

Comment: in line (4) when you divide by (a-b) you are assuming a-b>0 to obtain line (5) but assuming a-b<0 we obtain a<b that is $a\neq b$

Comment: Therefore from line (4) we can conclude that  $a\neq b$ which is the same result we obtain from line (7) since $$(a-b)^2>0 \iff a-b\neq 0 \iff a \neq b$$

Comment: Do you assume both $a,b$ being positive?

Comment: The inequality fails when $a = b$. Also if $ab < 0$, none of the reasoning is right, cause the inequality sign is reversed.

Comment: @xbh Yes of course we need a,b>0, I didn't noticed that it wasn't explicitely stated in the OP.

Comment: @Donsert Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ab<0 the given inequality is not true then assume $a,b>0$.

Note that from line $(4)$

$$a(a-b)>b(a-b)$$

dividing both sides by $a-b\neq 0$ we obtain

- $a>b$ when $a-b>0$
- $a<b$ when $a-b<0$

that is $a\neq b$ which is the same result we obtain from line $(6)$, indeed

$$a^2+b^2>2ab \iff a^2+b^2-2ab>0\iff(a-b)^2>0$$

wich is true for $a-b\neq 0 \iff a\neq b$,

Therefore your derivations are wrong in line $(5)$ and line $(8)$ which should be $a\neq b$.

As an alternative by [**Rearrangement inequality**](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Rearrangement_Inequality) for $(a,b)$ and $(1/a,1/b)$ we have that

$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\ge \frac{a}{a}+\frac{b}{b}=2$$

and equality holds if and only if $a=b$ therefore the given inequality holds for $a\neq b$.

Answer (score 2):

First solution is wrong here

\begin{align}
a(a-b)&>b(a-b)\tag 4\\
a&>b \tag 5
\end{align}
You can divide with $a-b$ if you know it is $>0$. If you want to divide with $a-b$ you should assume that $a>b$ (which you may because of simmetry).

Answer (score 0):

Im step 5 you use that $a-b$ is positive. So, also consider the negative variant here. I don't see why your Equation 8 is a logical consequence. Why don't you also include $a<b$ here?